# TypeScript's import() typeof json

Tags: typescript, react-native

I have a json file and I don't want to include it in runtime code, I only want to extract keyof that file and check type for input of function

I found out typescript hast import type in here https://davidea.st/articles/typescript-2-9-import-types

I try it and it's work for type checking

But I'm confused now, Is this solution work as well for json? **I don't want to load json at all in runtime code.**

I use **react-native**.

My example code

```
function(key: keyof typeof import('jsonfile.json'))
{

}
```

Comment: Why do you not want the json in runtime code? Can't find the reference but i'm pretty sure that if the JSON is part of the application code, i.e. it's imported, it's going to be bundled in with the application. Interested to know what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @LeeBrindley It's multi translation file and I import it dynamically base on user language

Comment: Interesting, I would be splitting each locale into it's own JSON file, with the same keys, then making a dictionary (object) of the locale references, and referencing (the keys) based on the user's current locale, e.g. set by the device. Hope that makes sense, I don't think the question is too clear, with the goal being " I don't want to load json at all in runtime code"

Comment: A type annotation will not be emited in the JS, so no import will occur. `key: keyof typeof import('jsonfile.json')` is a good way to just access thge type without any runtime penalty

Comment: @LeeBrindley I don't want to load it with some other code, because it's load dynamically, Also yes it's a dictianry file for each language and I don't want to load them all, I want to check type for my translator function that key exist in json

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir I'm confused so I ask the question, If you sure about that can you add an answer so I can mark it as currect answer, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type annotation are by definition erased when the code is compiled to Javascript. Any import type only be used in a type annotation so it will get removed after compilation.

You can check this yourself by examining the outputed JS:

```
// TS
function fn (key: keyof typeof import('jsonfile.json'))
{

}
// JS
function fn(key) {
}
```

[Play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMJAKA1gUwJ4C5FbZzCJTYAOmxiMAtuXAE5SoDkAVgM4LAwA2mAHRcErAJRiAUAG9JkgL5A)

Comment: Thanks, it's second time that you help me.